# How CLR handles extern method calls in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I want to ask why all extern method calls are static?
How the CLR handles these calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extern method calls are to unmanaged code. As such, it doesn't make sense to be called on a (managed) object instance - the first (hidden) argument in an instance method is the instance reference, aka `this`. Typically, `extern` methods just involve simple types (primitives, string, etc) - not objects (except perhaps arrays - and even they are often resolved to `IntPtr` first).

Answer (score 2):

`extern` calls also must generally conform to a "C-style" API, and C doesn't know anything about objects, thus the calls are `static`.

My statement isn't 100% true as there is a *ThisCall* calling convention which can be used with *[DllImport]* as an aid in calling C++ methods.